# Why is it difficult to calculate the ground state of a many-body quantum system?

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics, many-body

Assume N spin-1/2 particles, and only focus on the spin states. The dimension of the Hilbert space is then $2^N$. The ground state could be found by diagonalizng the Hamiltonian $H$. As is often stated, it is hard to find the ground state of $H$ when $N$ is large. My question is what is the largest $N$ that could be diagonalized (or has been diagonalized) on super computers? Assume $H$ is Hermitian and diagonalizable, but otherwise a "random" matrix with no special properties. I believe this $N$ should be importatnt for such claims, but has not found a satisfactory answer through a quick search of Google, or chatting with ChatGPT...

Comment: If H were a completely random matrix, it wouldn't even be possible to store it (or rather, storing it would be the actual bottleneck). This is *not* the relevant scenario.